# Need help in batch renaming files with bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, batch-file

I have some 50+ files in the following format :

```
abcd_vish_running_ZEBRA_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:23<br>
abcd_vish_running_ZEB-RA_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:35<br>
abcd_vish_running_ZEB_RA_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:37<br>
abcd_vish_running_RI-NG_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:42<br>
abcd_vish_running_RING_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:45<br>
abcd_vish_running_RI_NG_20140818.dat_08-14-2014_23:08:52<br>
```

**(ZEBRA,ZEB-RA,ZEB_RA,RI-NG,RING,RI_NG are given to just show the pattern)**

i need the to rename the above files to following format :

```
abcd_vish_running_ZEBRA_20140818.dat<br>
abcd_vish_running_ZEB-RA_20140818.dat<br>
abcd_vish_running_ZEB_RA_20140818.dat<br>
abcd_vish_running_RI-NG_20140818.dat<br>
abcd_vish_running_RING_20140818.dat<br>
abcd_vish_running_RI_NG_20140818.dat <br>
```

Now how to achieve this with shell scripting ?
I'm fairly new to scripting. Kindly help.

Cheers.

Comment: Do they always upvote lazy questions on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Using [rename](http://search.cpan.org/dist/rename/):

```
rename 's/[.]dat_.*/.dat/' *.dat_*
```

Using a `for` loop in Bash:

```
for F in *.dat_*; do
    echo mv -- "$F" "${F/%.dat_*/.dat}"
done
```

Remove `echo` when confirmed.

Using `mmv`:

```
mmv "*.dat_*" "#1.dat"
```

Comment: Wow! Nice answer! I don't really get why it is so simple atm. Can you explain how the date part gets reformatted?

Comment: Oh, now I see!! :) Missed that is was so simple. The date part was already part of the string.